# How to access the block id from the database id while using notion api?

Tags: notion-api

I have the database id but I want to access a block containing a pdf. The block is there in the page and the page is present in the database. So is there a way to access the block id from the database id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the database first to get the page_id, then use the [get block children](https://developers.notion.com/reference/get-block-children) endpoint to get the blocks of that page. You can then extract the PDF block

Comment: How will I get the blocks of that page using get block children as this itself requires block id?

Comment: The page id is the block id!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem!